# How to write curl --form using python requests

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, gitlab

I want to translate this curl command to python and I am having issue to write form properly:

```
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables/NEW_VARIABLE" --form "value=updated value"
```

I tried :

```
       files = {'file': ('somename.csv',  'value=updated value')} 

and 
        files = {}
        files['value'] = 'updated value' 
and 
files = dict(value=value_to_update)
```

The whole example:

```
        url = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables/bla?filter[environment_scope]=production'
        headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '<token>'
        }
        files = dict(value=value_to_update)
        x = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

**Solved**: This is how whole request in python using requests should look like
```

```
   headers = {
        'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '<token>',
    }

    files = {
        'value': (None, 'update value'),
    }

    response = requests.put('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables/variableKey', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: it's not clear if you try yo upload a simple value or a file because your initial curl doesn't refer to a file. What type of variable are you trying to upload ?

Comment: regular value string for example

Answer (score 0):

this is the conversion to python requests:

```
import requests

files = {
    'value': (None, 'updated value'),
}

response = requests.post('https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables/NEW_VARIABLE', files=files)
```